# Which tkinter modules were renamed in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a [file chooser dialog box](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/Fileopendialog.htm). However, when I try to import `tkMessageBox` in Python 3, I get an error claiming that the module does not exist.

```
import tkMessageBox
# ImportError: No module named 'tkMessageBox'
```

I get similar errors when trying to import other Tkinter modules in Python 3.

```
import Tkinter          # No module named 'Tkinter'
import tkColorChooser   # No module named 'tkColorChooser'
import tkFileDialog     # No module named 'tkFileDialog'
```

How do I import Tkinter modules in Python 3? What are the new module names?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The [`Tkinter` package from Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) has been renamed to [`tkinter` in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html), as well as other modules related to it.

Here is a list of renamed modules:

- [`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) → [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)
- `tkMessageBox` → `tkinter.messagebox`
- `tkColorChooser` → `tkinter.colorchooser`
- `tkFileDialog` → `tkinter.filedialog`
- `tkCommonDialog` → `tkinter.commondialog`
- `tkSimpleDialog` → `tkinter.simpledialog`
- `tkFont` → `tkinter.font`
- `Tkdnd` → `tkinter.dnd`
- [`ScrolledText`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/scrolledtext.html) → [`tkinter.scrolledtext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html)
- `Tix` → `tkinter.tix`
- `ttk` → `tkinter.ttk`

I advise you to learn how to dynamically browse the modules with the [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) command. If you are under windows, configure Python to use [readline](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/PyReadline/Intro) module to get auto-completion and make it much easier to list available classes in a module.

For a description of each module, refer to the official Python documentation. ([`Tkinter` in Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules), [`tkinter` in Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules))

Comment: Also note that tkinter.filedialog is a module (not a class imported from a module). So, to get the class, you would do from tkinter.filedialog import FileDialog. There appears to be no plain FileDialog class in Python 2.x, though. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### **Quick Script for using Tkinter / tkinter for Python 2.* & Python 3.***

I had a script which had different imports of Python 2.* Tkinter so browsing a but I see that the answer are all scattered. Here a small summary with a safe Script for using both Python versions.

```py
try:  # Python 2.7
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkColorChooser as color
    import tkCommonDialog as cdialog
    import Tkconstants as const
    import Tkdnd as dnd
    import tkFileDialog as fdialog
    import tkFont as font
    import tkMessageBox as msgbox
    import ScrolledText as stext
    import tkSimpleDialog as sdialog
    import Tix as tix
    import ttk

except ImportError:  # Python 3.* 
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import (
        colorchooser as color,
        commondialog as cdialog,
        constants as const,
        dialog,
        dnd,
        filedialog as fdialog,
        font,
        messagebox as msgbox,
        scrolledtext as stext,
        simpledialog as sdialog,
        tix,
        ttk
    )
```

### List of ModuleNotFoundError Errors (When Running Python 3.)

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkMessageBox'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ScrolledText'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkFileDialog'
```