# Fresh tutorial on tkinter and ttk for Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Where can I find the most modern tutorial that teaches [**`tkinter`**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tkinter.html) together with [**`ttk`**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tkinter.ttk.html)?

`Tkinter`  seems the only way to go in Python 3 (don't suggest Python 2), and `ttk` gave me hope for good-looking GUI.

Comment: Well, if Python 2 libraries aren't being ported to Python 3, let's transform Python 2 into Python 3........
`from __future__ import unicode_literals,division,print_function`, etc.

Comment: @Jbernardo, Tkinter is not as bad as it used to be, and you can make very nice GUIs with it. It uses the system's controls and themes better than previous versions did. You may have to work with the margins and padding a little to get better spacing. This is one thing PyQt does better right off the bat. PyQt is also a great library (and PyGTK), but you can still produce nice interfaces with Tkinter.

Comment: @JBernado: ugly is subjective, and a little out of touch with modern tk with themed widgets. Plus, most apps frankly don't need a lot of visual pizazz - functionality and/or ease of development is more often the driving factor.

Comment: @Bryan "functionality and/or ease of development" Dude, that's what PyQt is all about. Qt Designer is a great tool for interfaces

Comment: @BlaXpirit: Porting to Python 3 is a good idea. Do that! But it's way more complex than you indicate. Here's help! http://python3porting.com/

Comment: Suggesting PyQt against Tkinter is like suggesting Oracle against Sqlite.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I have found the [TkDocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) tutorial to be very useful. It describes building `Tk` interfaces using Python and `Tkinter` and `ttk` and makes notes about differences between Python 2 and 3. It also has examples in Perl, Ruby and Tcl, since the goal is to teach Tk itself, not the bindings for a particular language.

I haven't gone through the whole thing from start to finish, rather have only used a number of topics as examples for things I was stuck on, but it is very instructional and comfortably written. Today reading the intro and first few sections makes me think I will start working through the rest of it.

Finally, it's current and the site has a very nice look. He also has a bunch of other pages which are worth checking out (Widgets, Resources, Blog). This guy's doing a lot to not only teach Tk, but also to improve people's understanding that it's not the ugly beast that it once was.

Comment: My bone with this tutorial is that the examples in the tutorial look, for a lack of a better word, ugly. If one wants to dispell the myth that tk apps look not nice shouldnt one teach ppl how to do it right?

Answer (score 20):

I recommend the [NMT Tkinter 8.5 reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html).

- [Themed widgets](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk.html)
- [Customizing and creating ttk themes and styles](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-themes.html)
- [Finding and using themes](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-theme-layer.html)
- [Using and customizing ttk styles](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html)
- [The ttk element layer](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-element-layer.html)

The module names used in some examples are those used in Python 2.7.
Here's a reference for the name changes in Python 3: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673309/1217270)

One of the conveniences of [ttk](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.ttk.html) is that you can choose a preexisting [theme](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-themes.html),
which is a full set of [Styles](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html) applied to the [ttk](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.ttk.html) widgets.

Here's an example I wrote (for Python 3) that allows you to select any available theme from a *Combobox*:

```
import random
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class App(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        available_themes = self.style.theme_names()
        random_theme = random.choice(available_themes)
        self.style.theme_use(random_theme)
        self.root.title(random_theme)

        frm = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        frm.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    # create a Combobox with themes to choose from
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(frm, values=available_themes)
        self.combo.pack(padx=32, pady=8)
    # make the Enter key change the style
        self.combo.bind('<Return>', self.change_style)
    # make a Button to change the style
        button = ttk.Button(frm, text='OK')
        button['command'] = self.change_style
        button.pack(pady=8)

    def change_style(self, event=None):
        """set the Style to the content of the Combobox"""
        content = self.combo.get()
        try:
            self.style.theme_use(content)
        except tkinter.TclError as err:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', err)
        else:
            self.root.title(content)

app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```

Side note: I've noticed that there is a 'vista' theme available when using Python 3.3 (but not 2.7).

Comment: The NMT reference is an ***Excellent*** resource.  I keep the _tkinter_ [pdf version](http://www.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf) open whenever I am working with `tkinter`

Comment: NMT seems to have stopped hosting the tkinter reference. [PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20190203155416/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html). It is simple and authoritative, and good for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really fresh but [this](http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net) is concise, and from what I've seen valid either for Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Not a word about **ttk**

Comment: Oh yikers, overlooked that part ^_^ though they are fairly interchangeable from the bit I've seen.