# How to attach a Scrollbar to a Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to attach a scrollbar to my Text field and have been unable to do so. Here is the segment of code:

```
self.scroller = Scrollbar(self.root)
self.scroller.place(x=706, y=121)
self.outputArea = Text(self.root, height=26, width=100) 
self.outputArea.place(x=0, y=120)
self.scroller.config(command=self.outputArea.yview)
self.outputArea.config(state=DISABLED, yscrollcommand = self.scroller.set)
```

This code is placing a very small scrollbar right next to my text field (and by very small, I mean that you can see the up and down arrows but nothing in between). I can scroll with it when my text field fills up, but is there a way to at the very least set the height of the scrollbar so that it appears to be the same height as the text field?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[Tkinter](https://web.archive.org/web/20190203155416/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf) has three *geometry managers*: [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm), [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), and [place](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).
Pack and grid are usually recommended over place.

You can use the [*grid manager's*](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method) *row* and *column* options
to position the *Scrollbar* next to the *Text* widget.

Set the *Scrollbar* widget's *command* option to the Text's *yview* method.

```
scrollb = tkinter.Scrollbar(..., command=txt.yview)
```

Set the *Text* widget's *yscrollcommand* option to the Scrollbar's *set* method.

```
txt['yscrollcommand'] = scrollb.set
```

Here's a working example that makes use of [ttk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15081982/1217270):

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class TextScrollCombo(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # ensure a consistent GUI size
        self.grid_propagate(False)
    # implement stretchability
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # create a Text widget
        self.txt = tkinter.Text(self)
        self.txt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

    # create a Scrollbar and associate it with txt
        scrollb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.txt.yview)
        scrollb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.txt['yscrollcommand'] = scrollb.set

main_window = tkinter.Tk()

combo = TextScrollCombo(main_window)
combo.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
combo.config(width=600, height=600)

combo.txt.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
combo.txt.config(borderwidth=3, relief="sunken")

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

main_window.mainloop()
```

The part that will address your *Scrollbar* being small is `sticky='nsew'`,
which you can read about → [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method).

Something that will be helpful for you to learn right now is that different *Tkinter* widgets can use different *geometry managers* within the same program **as long as they do not share the same parent**.

---

The [*tkinter.scrolledtext*](http://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html) module contains a class called *ScrolledText* which is a compound widget (Text & Scrollbar).

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolledtext

main_window = tkinter.Tk()

txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(main_window, undo=True)
txt['font'] = ('consolas', '12')
txt.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

main_window.mainloop()
```

The way this is [implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/scrolledtext.py) is worth taking a look at.

Comment: I would change "usually recommended over place" to "*always* recommended over place". place is useful, but only for rare situations.

Comment: Use the `tkinter.scrolledtext` solution, it's easier :)

Answer (score 17):

If you're working with an INPUT box, then a handy way using the `scrolledtext` function.  It took me 4+ hours to find it.  Don't ya love tkinter?

Two things to note...
The additional import required
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkscrolled
and you set default value using `insert` and read the value using `get` (more terrible naming)

This bit of code was central to making my 20 character wide by 10 lines text input box to work.

```
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkscrolled
import tkinter as tk

default_text = '1234'
width, height = 20,10
TKScrollTXT = tkscrolled.ScrolledText(10, width=width, height=height, wrap='word')

# set default text if desired
TKScrollTXT.insert(1.0, default_text)
TKScrollTXT.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

The scroll bars show up once reaching the height as defined in the call. They are grayed out and blend into the background well.  It works great..... once you figure out the correct calls to make.

I hope this is relevant to your question!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be defined in tkinter for `TkVersion == 8.6`

Answer (score 4):

You can use tkinter frame for it, this is very simple way =>

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()

f = tk.Frame(root)
f.place(x=10, y=20)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(f)
t = tk.Text(f, height=10, width=10, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=t.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
t.pack(side="left")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would work. This is a piece of my code that I used on mine. There are some other options that you can remove. I have them because my theme is dark.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("test for scrollbar")
window.config(pady=50, padx=50, bg="white")


text_box = Text(width=49, height=5, bg="white", highlightthickness=1, foreground="black",
                    insertbackground="black", wrap="word")
    tex_scroll = Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL,)
    
    tex_scroll.config(command=text_box.yview, )
    text_box["yscrollcommand"] = tex_scroll.set
    
    text_box.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2, sticky="w")
    tex_scroll.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky="nse")

window.mainloop()
```