# How to add a scrollbar to the Tkinter textbox widget

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have recently re-visited one of my older GUI projects, and have decided that its text widgets need a vertical scroll-bar as the output is often quite long. I have been unable to find this on my own and was wondering if I could have some help. Here is the necessary code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.widget()
    def widget(self):
        self.results_plain_label = Label(self,
                                         text = "Deciphered Message")
        self.results_plain_label.grid(row = 13, column =5, pady = 5 )
        self.results_plain_text = Text (self, width = 100, height = 6,
        wrap = WORD, font ("Times New Roman", ))
        self.results_plain_text.grid(row = 14, column = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W)

Mainloop initialization stuff
```

So, how would I add a `scroll-bar` to the `results_plain_text` textbox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13832720/1217270

Comment: I recommend these references: [NMT](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) and [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm).

Comment: Thank you! So those sites cover python or Tkinter mainly? @Honestabe

Comment: They both have a lot of information about Python: [link1](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/lang/python/docs.html), [link2](http://effbot.org/librarybook/).