# How to add a scroll bar to a text box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add a scroll bar to a text box which makes up part of my GUI.

So far I have made the text box and (i think) the scroll bar but dont know how to combine the two items.

```
textBox_1 = Text(myGUI).place(x=75, y=300)
scroll_1 = Scrollbar(myGUI)
scroll_1.configure()
```

Comment: [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13833338/1217270)

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps that you need to take: you need to connect the scrollbar to the widget, and you need to connect the widget to the scrollbar. For example:

```
textBox_1 = Text(...)
scroll_1 = Scrollbar(...)
textBox_1.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_1.set)
scroll_1.configure(command=textBox_1.yview)
```

Also, I notice that you called `place` as part of widget creation. You cannot do that. When you do `Text(...).place(...)` it stores the result of `place` in `textbox_1`, *not* the result of `Text(...)`. Plus, it's just easier to maintain your code when the layout is separate from widget creation.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
textbox_1.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_1.set)
```

Comment: i get an AttributeError: NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: Putting place in the command means it is not returning the Text widget.  Separate onto two lines.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Tkinter`, no matter what geometry manager you're using, you need to create your widget and use the geometry manager on separate lines if you want to keep a reference to the Widget.  In other words, `Widget.place` returns `None` (as does `Widget.pack` and `Widget.grid`).

```
textBox_1 = Text(myGUI)
textBox_1.place(x=75, y=300)
scroll_1 = Scrollbar(myGUI)
textbox_1.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_1.set)
```

Comment: it compiles but the scroll bar isn't on the textbox

Comment: You still need to pack or place the scrollbar

Comment: is there a way i can make it stretch so its the same height as the text box?

Comment: I've never used a scrollbar with place.  Can you use pack?

Comment: @stark: you can use pack, place or grid. I can't imagine a scenario where place makes the most sense. With all three there are configuration options to have the widget stretch or shrink, though the options are different for each (since they work in fundamentally different ways).