# How to add scrollbar in text widget in tkinter python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

I am searching how to add scrollbar to text widget in tkinter,I have went through many of questions and answers but they were using pack geometry manager whereas I want to use place geometry manager and I have also tried using place geometry manager although it is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13833338/14094985 does this answer your question? Why exactly do you want to use the place geometry manager over the others?

Comment: "not working" is not a useful description. Please show what you've tried. Scrollbars are no different than any other widget with respect to placement, though I strongly encourage you not to use `place`. `pack` and `grid` are better at creating responsive guis without  you having to compute the x/y coordinates and widths of widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple, use

```
tkinter.scrolledtext
```

Comment: `tkinter.scrolledtext` is the module name, better mention the `ScrolledText` class which is the widget to be used.