# Add scrollbar in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
box=Text(window)
scrollbar=Scrollbar(window, orient=VERTICAL, command=box.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
box.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

I have created a large program with tkinter to create graphical interface. I tried to add scrollbar but it doesn't work.

It doesn^t move up and down

Comment: Hey, would you mind providing some detail along with the code? Otherwise your asnwer may be deleted. Thanks!

Comment: There's a Scrolledtext widget that has the scrollbar in the Text widget that.
Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832720/how-to-attach-a-scrollbar-to-a-text-widget