# python + tkinter - is there a way to have a text box with a dynamically updating text variable and a scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

I am trying to create a GUI with a text box that automatically appends status messages during the execution of a program. I can use a Label widget with a textvariable to update the text, but as far as I can tell, I can't add a scrollbar to a Label. I can add a scrollbar to a Text widget, but I can't use a textvariable to populate that widget.

I feel like there is a simple answer, but I haven't been able to find it.

This is the working Label without a scrollbar:

```
self.status_window = tk.Label(
    self.status_window_pane,
    height=5,
    width=50,
    textvariable=self.status_messages,
    relief=GROOVE,
    bg="white",
    fg="black",
    anchor="nw",
    justify=LEFT,
)
```

Comment: A `Text` is exactly what you want, but you'd need to call `.insert()` on it to add content rather than using a StringVar.

Comment: `self.statusmessages` implies it has more than one message. Is this a list variable or a tkinter `StringVar`, or something else?

Comment: @BryanOakley - I am collecting the messages into a list and then appending the messages to my StringVar with a newline character. The StringVar that is displayed in the Label is a tkinter StringVar.

Comment: Why do you need to use a `StringVar` for the messages? Why not just directly update the text widget when you update the list?

Comment: I was using a 'StringVar' for the messages as I could update the variable in a different loop and the GUI would automatically update with the new content. Looks like this should still be available with the 'text.insert()' method.

Comment: Yes, you can replace `self.status_messages.set(...)` with `self.the_text_widget.insert(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `textvariable` to populate a text widget, you can use its `insert` method:

```
text = tk.Text(...)

# After some event

text.insert('1.0', content) # 1.0 is the text indice
```

Some links:

- [More info on text indices](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html)
- [How to attach a Scrollbar to a Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832720/how-to-attach-a-scrollbar-to-a-text-widget)

Comment: This works great to get the messages into the text box with a scrollbar. However, when I was using a StringVar, I could call update_idletasks() to asynchronously update the display. Is there a similar way to update using text.insert? As of right now, it only updates when the calling function completes rather than throughout the calling function.

Comment: @JacobF. It should still work, do you have an example you can show using `update_idletasks` where it does n't work?

Comment: you are correct, it does still work. Just a simple error on my end.