# How to use a file dialog in tkinter to get a filename?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a small program to enter a file name in an entry dialog in python tkinter. The code currently using a entry dialog which lets me put in a file name manually. However, I wish to use the file browser kind of feature in place of manual typing in of the file. To add on, I wish to not open the file in the dialog itself but rather store the entire path to a variable. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 4):

Use `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()`, as described in a  [tkinter.unpythonic.net](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) webpage.

`askopenfilename(**options)` gets a name or names and has options `defaultextension, filetypes, initialdir, initialfile, multiple, message, parent, title`

Comment: In python 3, [the API changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673309/3077939) a little, so the dialog is now `tkinter.filedialog`.