# Error when building a project

Tags: python, build, installation, setup.py

I cloned an [organism](https://github.com/kynikos/organism.git) project from github.

I tried to install it, but there is no one `setup.py` file and no documentation.

Could you advise me how to correctly build and install it under Ubuntu 12.04?

I tried so far:

`sudo python3 organism.setup.py install`

which shows error message:

```
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/organism/coreaux/configuration.py to configuration.pyc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/organism/coreaux/configuration.py", line 31
    _USER_FOLDER_PERMISSIONS = 0750
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

and running it shows this error message:

```
$ organism
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/organism", line 23, in <module>
    organism.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/organism/__init__.py", line 21, in main
    import coreaux
ImportError: No module named coreaux
```

I'm not sure if I should use all the files `organism-development.setup.py`, `organism-organizer.setup.py`, `organism.setup.py`, `organism-tk.setup.py` in the build process or the error is elsewhere.

Comment: Looks like it's a python 2.x project. AFAIK, Python 3.x doesn't support octal numbers of the form `0750`.

Comment: The site says it is for python 2 not 3

Comment: @Kevin @fp I thought it myself but it's for Python 3 because of `tkinter`. See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673174/file-dialog-in-tkinter-python-3)

Comment: From the site: `force the execution with Python 2 `. You can get in touch with [kynikos](https://github.com/kynikos)