# Can't seem to import Tkinter for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Hello and thanks for looking at this,

When I try to import tkinter it says unresolved import

ImportError: No module named tkinter

There was some kind of error when I installed python originally

Here are the paths:

Output:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-     scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/Users/wes/Desktop/UM/Python/guiTest
/Users/wes/Desktop/UM/Python/guiTest/testgui
```

Thanks
-Wes

Comment: In Python 2.7, the module should be called `Tkinter`, with a capital T.  Could you try `import Tkinter`?

Comment: See if there's a `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py` -- again note the capital `T`.

Comment: I have Tkinter.pyo and Tkinter.pyc but no Tkinter.py

Comment: More info: I am trying to use the MessageBox. If I comment every thing else out the first import "from Tkinter import *" seems to be ok

Comment: If the error is `No module named tkinter` (with lowercase T) then the problem is that you are trying to import Tkinter with the name of Python 3. Could you post the code with all the import statements?

Comment: from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

def beenClicked():
    radioValue = relStatus.get()
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("You clicked", radioValue)
    return

def changeLabel():
    name = "Thanks for the click " + yourName.get()
    labelText.set(name)
    yourName.delete(0, END)
    yourName.insert(0, "My name is Derek")
    return

app = Tk()
app.title("GUI Example")
app.geometry('450×300+200+200')

Comment: sorry I forgot "return" sends the comment. This code is from new think tank and it works when Derek does it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which tkinter modules were renamed in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673174/which-tkinter-modules-were-renamed-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `tkinter` with lowercase T. The code you posted in your comment is for Python 3.X, and the import statements are correct if you have that version too, but since you are using Python 2.7, the names for the modules are `Tkinter` and `tkMessageBox` (instead of `tkinter` and `tkinter.messagebox`).

Comment: Thank you for your post. Unfortunately it is still giving me the "unresolved import" compile time message while using Tkinter and tkMessageBox

Comment: @user2395350 Which OS are you using? Can you check if there exists `_tkinter` in the `libs` (with s) folder?

Comment: I am using osx, It allows me to import _tkinter but I am not sure what  libs (with s) means. I don't see a folder like that.

Comment: _tkinter is a module written in C that Tkinter needs to work. All this modules are in the libs folder (usually in the same directory as Lib). If you had a problem during the installation, I suggest you to install Python 3 directly and take a look also to http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out! Thanks. My mac comes with python 2.7 in system/Library and auto config defalts to this however this is not the version that I downloaded and updated.The version that I downloaded went into Library not System and the Capital T in Tkinter was important as you said for 2.7 Thanks for your help