# How to save text form a textbox (String and Int) in python 3.x tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, save

I am trying to save some names and values from 6 texboxes, 2 are Strings and 4 are Integers, in .txt or .doc but it is not working

I am using python 3.4 in windows 8.1, can somebody help me, I have not being able to find any info or example in python 3.4 to save whatever I write in those 6 texboxes
I have a button to call the function mSave

I have the following code to save but is not working

```
def mSave():
    filename = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt',
                                 filetypes=(('Text files', '*.txt'),
                                            ('Python files', '*.py *.pyw'),
                                            ('All files', '*.*')))
  if filename:
     with open(filename, 'w') as stream:
          stream.write(self.gettext())
```

Python says

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 121, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\queue.py", line 175, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\\ManualTab.py", line 608, in mSave
    filename = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt',
NameError: name 'asksaveasfilename' is not defined
```

pleae help

Comment: Can you provide complete code example.

Comment: For the import problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/673309/3714930

Comment: What does "not successful" mean? Does the program crash? Does it write the wrong data? Do you get errors? Also, except for the import statements, the same code will work in just about all versions of python to save data to a file.

Comment: I have errors, I will put the code in the question

Comment: The error is telling you the oroblem: you are calling a function that you haven't defined nor imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer

ok first of all, for python 3.4 I have to use

```
from tkinter import *
```

but it does NOT mean that it will import ALL so I have to call

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
```

and it is the same with open if somebody need it

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
```

NOW FINALLY I CAN CALL MY FUNCTION

```
def mSave():
  filename = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt',filetypes = (('Text files', '*.txt'),('Python files', '*.py *.pyw'),('All files', '*.*')))
  if filename is None:
    return
  file = open (filename, mode = 'w')
  name1 = TubeLenghtVal_1.get()          
  name2 = TubeLenghtVal_2.get()

  # or whatever you assign the name of the variable, for me is TubeLenghtVal_2 = StringVar() and for integer I have Vol_Val = IntVar()
  all = name1 + " , " + name + " , " + (str(Vol_Val))
  file.write(all)
  file.close()
```

and that is all