# Python3 Tkinter fonts not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, tkinter, python-import

I am using python 3.3 with tkinter, and the package python3-tk is installed. In most docs the old "import tkFont" is used, which is not working any more.

This is supposed to work:

```
from tkinter import font
appHighlightFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight='bold')
font.families()
```

However, I get this exception on the second line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/tkinter/font.py", line 92, in __init__
    root.tk.call("font", "create", self.name, *font)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

I checked http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/fonts.html and http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html which were the most useful tkinter docs so far.

Unfortunately I still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Related: [Which tkinter modules were renamed in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673174/3357935)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should import `font` not `fonts`. Also, if the code you posted is actual code, you are neglecting to create a root window before working with fonts. You must create a root window first.

```
from tkinter import font
import tkinter as tk
...
root = tk.Tk()
...
appHighlightFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight='bold')
font.families()
```

Comment: You are right, I edited the code above. I still receive an error.

Comment: @percidae: you need to create a root window before working with fonts.

Comment: Now it seems to work.
Wierd, since I stumbled upon this mistake in a *.py-File with a root-Window.
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

window = Tk()
window.geometry("350x400")
window.title("tkinter!")

lbl = Label(window, text="this is a lable", size=12)
lbl.pack()

sleep(1)

lbl.configure(text="now it is a big lable", size=48)
```