# No attribute "call" error in tkinter font

Tags: python, exception, tkinter

I am devoloping one desktop application using **tkinter** . Setting font raising exception .

`tmp.py`

```
def main(root):
    frame = Frame(root.master)
    font = Font(size=25 , weight="bold")
    label = Label(frame , font=font , text="tuna fish")
    label.pack()
    frame.pack()
```

**this is driver program main.py**
`main.py`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = start.baseApp()
    root.Menu_Customer.add_command(label="New customer", command=lambda: tmp.main(root=root))
    root.master.mainloop()
```

> baseApp

i have created root window and menu bar with name **Customer** and added menu item **New customer in `main.py`**.

i am getting the exception in `tmp.py`saying

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1559, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 10, in <lambda>
    root.Menu_Customer.add_command(label="New customer", command=lambda: tmp.main(root=root))
  File "/home/engle/Documents/Project/CleanMaster/tmp.py", line 6, in main
    font = Font(size=25 , weight="bold")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/tkinter/font.py", line 93, in __init__
    tk.call("font", "create", self.name, *font)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call'
```

whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Did you include this line: `import tmp` ?

Comment: of course man. i imported that.

Comment: I cannot run your code and therefore cannot troubleshoot it, please review this and amend accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What @EthanField said is true, there are missing information that do not allow us to debug and check your code. If you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to work with the `Font` class in tkinter, [an instance of `Tk()` must be running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32660421/4084269). If you have such an instance running, try to explicitly pass it as argument to your font:

```
def main(root):
    ...
    font = Font(root=root.master, size=25 , weight="bold")
    ...
```