# Is there a message box which displays copy-able text in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, msgbox

I'm trying to write a Python program that gets a string as input and displays the string in a message box with the last letter removed from each word.
I've successfully written the code to remove the last letter from each word and I came to know about the tkinter module.
But the text isn't copy-able from tk message box. 
Is there any other way to display a message box with copy-able text?
If there's no way to display such message boxes, is there any way to display the output in a copy-able form without displaying a message box?
Additional (useless) information:

1. The name of this language is fromonk(In case you were wondering why the var name fromonk_text)
2. Smileys should be displayed in whole.(Including the last letter).Hence the if-else block.

The code I've written:

```
import tkMessageBox
line="foo"
while line!="exit":
    fromonk_text=""
    line=raw_input()
    words=line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word.startswith(":"):
            fromonk_text+=word+" "
        else:
            fromonk_text+=word[0:len(word)-1]+" "
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Fromonk",fromonk_text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing built-in. You can create your own popup dialog with a `Toplevel` widget that contains a `Text` widget and some `Button` widgets, or you can use tkSimpleDialog

Some documentation can be found here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Here's a simple working example. It allows the text to be edited, but you can disable that if you want.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkSimpleDialog

class CustomDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent, title=None, text=None):
        self.data = text
        tkSimpleDialog.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title=title)

    def body(self, parent):

        self.text = tk.Text(self, width=40, height=4)
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.text.insert("1.0", self.data)

        return self.text

def show_dialog():
    fromonk_text = "this is an example"
    CustomDialog(root, title="Example", text=fromonk_text)

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=show_dialog)
button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Example Window]

Comment: [For Python 3 users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673309/3357935), rename the following imports: `Tkinter` → `tkinter`, `tkSimpleDialog` → `tkinter.simpledialog`

Comment: This answer serves as a nice example of how to inherit / override the `tkSimpleDialog` class if that's the right way of wording it. I'm interested because this class has `self.wait_window(self)` which hopefully allows tkinter run in background until user clicks button.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: tkinter doesn't "run in the background". Tkinter is single-threaded. What `wait_window` does is allow `mainloop` to continue to process events, but function won't return until the dialog is destroyed.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm not sure what `mainloop` is supposed to do but I can say that all `tkinter` windows freeze when `wait_window` runs in `tkSimpleDialog` so i will have to make a special dialog box background process like all the other windows I've had to create so that all `tkinter` windows run concurrently.  I'll do that later though because I've so much more code to write. Thank you for your kind patience explaining things to me so often.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: I've never seen all windows freeze when calling `wait_window`.  In fact, in a sense that function was created specifically so that the windows would _not_ freeze. All `mainloop` does it continuously process events from the event queue. It's barely more than a `while` loop, and `wait_window` is barely more than `mainloop` with an extra check to see if the window exists before returning.