# Pyinstaller, .py version works, .exe "No module named Tkinter"?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I don't understand how this happened. myscript.py works, Tkinter is installed. However once I converted it to .exe using pyinstaller, I ran myscript.exe, I got a message in command prompt saying "No module named Tkinter".

How can I fix this?
I've already tried to convert it several times, tried using --noupx, and also tried reinstalling pyinstaller. Thanks

Comment: There are --windowed and --hidden-import flags ... refer the docs.

Comment: Related: [Which tkinter modules were renamed in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673174/3357935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PyInstaller - Hidden Imports

Try using the `--hiddenimport` flag. Do `--hiddenimport=Tkinter`, or replace the `Tkinter` with whatever module you need. The issue seems reoccurring throughout the PyInstaller community. [Here is one article](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1584).

### Name Space

Tkinter has changed its namespaces from Python 2 to Python 3. It's now named `tkinter` in Python 3 and `Tkinter` in Python 2. This is the code I like to use so it's cross-version.

```
try:
  import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
  import tkinter as tk
```

Then you can reference Tkinter as `tk`. Or if you do `from Tkinter import *` you can just use everything without a namespace. See the list [here](http://python3porting.com/stdlib.html) for more of the name changes between version.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that is the issue as the script works, the problem occurs when I try to convert it to .exe

Comment: Made a few edits, the issue seems to be occurring with PyInstaller with most people. There are a few articles on the [PyInstaller GitHub](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Module%20not%20Found) for this.